# session error while running project on android studio

Tags: android, session, android-studio, package-name

I have changed the package name, it's changed in manifest, classes and everywhere but still when i create it it gets the old one which is com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard which should be thesherlabs.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard and gives the following error;

please help

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: Nexus_5_API_21_x86 [emulator-5554]
Uploading file
local path: C:\Users\shershah.rahim\Desktop\Sher Shah\AnySoftKeyboard-master\build\outputs\apk\AnySoftKeyboard-master-debug.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard
Installing com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard
Success


Launching application: com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard/thesherlabs.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard.Laun  cherSettingsActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n "com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard/thesherlabs.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard.LauncherSettingsActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]     cmp=com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard/thesherlabs.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard.LauncherSettingsActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard/thesherlabs.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard.LauncherSettingsActivity} does not exist.
```

Comment: `Error: Activity class {com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard/thesherlabs.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard.LauncherSettingsActivity} does not exist.` Check this exact path in your project folders.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project folder. Open ProjectName folder.
Look in here for your settings. Most of the google posts are for the remote path not existing.  But they all say to go to your project .iml file in the project folder.

Comment: Depending on your operating system...
Windows: open file explorer.  Click the search button...you can tell it to search inside of files for a string. Point it at your project directory and see what comes up for menny.android.

Linux: traverse the directory tree and run grep "menny" *  or grep remote * or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the commands it's spitting out.

> DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n "com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard/thesherlabs.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard.LauncherSettingsActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER

Notice how the path is a concatenation of your old package name and your new package name. This means that in one of your setup files (most likely the Manifest), you probably added in your new package name without actually removing the old one. Post the contents of your AndroidManifest.xml and maybe the community can help a little better.